# Android list item focus doesnot stay onItemLongclickListener

Tags: android

I have serious problem with listview item. My requirement is  When I am **long clicking on list item or dragging on list item**  the focus should stay. Currently I am using the following selector for list item. But It is not giving me the expected result and the focus is getting lost

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/detail_btn_frame_select" /> 
<item android:state_selected="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/detail_btn_frame_select" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/detail_btn_frame_select" />
 //Default
 <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/detail_btn_frame_norm" />
```

Please do help in this

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
android:state_focused="true"
```

In your selector xml

Comment: I used focused also but getting same result Murali